# ViewHolder pattern - How to correctly update views

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

While implementing the viewHolder pattern in an extended ArrayAdapter, and implementing an onClickListener on a Linear Layout, the background color of this LinearLayout gets changed **but for other random rows as well!**

Here is my code (Have stripped down the viewHolder to only include the error):

```
public class CustomFeedsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomCommunityQuestion>{

    private static final String TAG = "CustomFeedsAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<CustomCommunityQuestion> customCommunityQuestions;

    public CustomFeedsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomCommunityQuestion> customCommunityQuestions) {
        super(context, -1, customCommunityQuestions);
        this.context = context;
        this.customCommunityQuestions = customCommunityQuestions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        // reuse views
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cards_feeds_row, null, false);
            holder.buttonFollow = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.follow_layout);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        final CustomCommunityQuestion currentQuestion = customCommunityQuestions.get(position);

        // Set onClick Listeners
        holder.buttonFollow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                VolleySingleton volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context);
                StringRequest followJsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        "http://private-e9644-popxoandroid.apiary-mock.com/quest_follow/1/0",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    Log.d(TAG, response);
                                    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                    String message = responseObject.getString("message");
                                    Integer success = responseObject.getInt("success");
                                    Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    if(success!=0){
                                        holder.buttonFollow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.holo_blue_bright); // Here the button I wish to update doesn't get the color, but instead some weird random row's button get's changed.
                                        holder.buttonFollow.setEnabled(false);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "There was some error! You were unable to follow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                error.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e(TAG,error.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                volleySingleton.addToRequestQueue(followJsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private LinearLayout buttonFollow;
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey Saket, You can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622883/settext-changes-at-multiple-times-in-textview. Some one added a comment Which I believe is a right answer.

Comment: Seriously I never used POJO classes, What I prefer is in your onclick listener download whatever you want and then dont update the UI there rather update the dataset of your adapter and reload the list using  notifyDataSetChanged(); and in getView handle the UI thats all. Believe me it works am using the same solution in my project :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari: Hmmm.. Sort of makes sense, but I would rather keep the UI functionality separate from the core class if possible. Let's see if some answer can help me out with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you are doing**

The currently visible rows are at let's say position 0,1,2. You are updating a particular *ViewHolder* that is already been set as the tag of a particular (for use of a better word) - view. This view is then re-used later on when you call `holder = (ViewHolder)rowview.getTag()`. Let's assume for the purpose of this explanation that you are updating view at position 1.

**What happens when you scroll a listView**

As you scroll a listview, the old view is re-used by getting the holder from the tag. This means that the view that you changed earlier is now being re-used.

**What you need to do instead**

So when you need to update your view, first of all update a relevant variable. For example:

Create an attribute in your CustomCommunityQuestion class and implement a getter and setter like this:

```
boolean isBlue;

public void setIsBlue(booelan isblue){
     this.isBlue = isblue;
}

public boolean isBlue(){
    return isBlue;
}
```

Now in your button onClickListener, you can set the variable isBlue to yes, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Moreover, handle the attribute isBlue like so:

*Just check the isBlue state and set the color accordingly*

```
if(customCommunityQuestions.get(position).isBlue()){
       holder.buttonFollow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.holo_blue_bright);
}else{
     holder.buttonFollow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I was implementing the solution as you wrote, but your approach is better. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the recycling of the listitems:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    // reuse views
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        ...
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        //!!!
        // here the view item is recycled but
        // holder.buttonFollow is not reset to its initial state
    }
```

Solution: your `CustomFeedsAdapter` must remeber success-stat for every item

Comment: Thanks k3b. I think I am getting what you are saying. However, could you please tell if there is a best-practice approach or something for remembering the success-stat? I think that would be really helpful. :)